# calling/using the given attribute

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tags, treenode

I have not done anything in `Tag` for `treenode`. Then it is maybe very simple question. I googled through internet and could not find something helpful.

I am giving assigning some Tags for tree nodes via

```
public class NodeTag
{
    public NodeTag(string name, string ID)//, bool component, string script, bool child) //,ref parrent
    {
        NodeName = name;
        NodeID = ID;
    }
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public string NodeID { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to call nodes using it Tag. I want to access to the `NodeName`. I tried as

```
var value = node.Tag;
```

But it gives me both fields as one should expected. I have an error if I use

```
var value = node.Tag.NodeID;
```

Would you please help me?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Tag property has the Object type to provide ability to store any object as a node tag. You must cast an object stored in a Tag property to the required type, especially to the NodeTag.

```
var id = ((NodeTag)node.Tag).NodeID
```

You can add a few extension methods to make it reader friendly

```
public static int GetNodeID(this Node node)
{
    return ((NodeTag)node?.Tag).NodeID;
}
```

Now you can use it

```
var id = node.GetNodeID();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = node.Tag as NodeTag;
string node_ID = value.NodeID;
```